# In the double slit experiment for electrons, what are the materials used for the detection screen?

Tags: double-slit-experiment

for example, what material is used as the detection screen for electrons. What materials can be used when conducting the experiment to be able to see the detected electrons on the detection screen?

Comment: Almost any phosphor, like those used for CRTs (not surprisingly). The classic one is zinc sulfide which dates back to the early days of cathode rays, alpha particles, etc.

Comment: Or nearly any photographic emulsion. Or CCDs or silicon PMTs, or, or, or... There are lots of ways to detect electrons.

Comment: ... microchannel plate ...

Comment: In experiment shown in Wikipedia single electron at at time  , the provider of the image ( dr Tanamura , https://www.hitachi.com/rd/portal/highlight/quantum/doubleslit/index.html  )   says they used a Hamamtsu  photon detector (PIAS) https://www.hamamatsu.com/eu/en/our-company/history/index.html for detecting  the single electrons

Comment: You can use DRZ screen with a normal CCD camera

Answer (score 0):

In these italian experiments, there is no slit but a electron beam divider, and particles are detected with photographic paper or on a tv monitor.

Movie : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zc-iyjpzzGQ&feature=youtu.be

Summary : https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4617474/

The Merli–Missiroli–Pozzi Two-Slit Electron-Interference Experiment

"They obtained an interference pattern with an electron microscope that was fitted with a special interferometer, an electron biprism, that consisted basically of a very thin wire oriented perpendicularly to the electron beam and positioned symmetrically between two plates at ground potential, so that when a positive or negative potential was applied to the wire the electron beam was split into two deflected components. "

"Their use of this electron biprism was the first important technical and conceptual feature of their experiment; the second was its ability to observe the continuous arrival of the electrons, one at a time, on a television monitor. "